# Mount different remote systems

Tags: shell, sh

I have a shell script to mount different remote systems. While it does work, the area I struggle with (not being a programmer) is the logic of the script: it feels quite stilted and there seems to be some unnecessary duplication.

I would appreciate any comments as to how I could improve it - both in terms of the logic, but also any other tips about style or approach.

```
#!/bin/sh
# mount boxes by SSHFS

usage () {
    cat <<EOF
    sshmnt -[c,s,u,h]
      -c Box1
      -s Box2
      -u unmount
      -h print this message

EOF
}

mnt(){
    sshfs jason@"$host":/home/jason /media/"$dir" \
    -C -p "$port" \
    -o reconnect,IdentityFile=/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && ls /media/"$dir"
}

umnt(){
    fusermount -u /media/"$dir"
}

# unmounting 
if [ "$1" = "-u" ]; then
    box=$(mount | grep Box1)
    if [ -n "$box" ]; then
        dir=Box1
    else
        dir=Box2
    fi
    umnt && exit
fi

# check if on LAN
lan="$(ip addr | grep .102/)"

if [ -n "$lan" ]; then 
    case "$1" in
      -c) int=100
          ;;
      -s) int=200 
          ;;
    esac
    host="192.168.1.$int"
else
    host="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
fi

# box specifics
case "$1" in
  -c) dir=Box1 port="XXXX"
      mnt
      ;;
  -s) dir=Box2  port="XXXX"
      mnt
      ;;
   *) usage && exit
       ;;
esac
```

I have obscured the relevant ports and hostnames.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your functions shouldn't depend on variables but use specified
parameters. You always specified variables before calling your function instead of just specifying them as parameters, e.g:

```
DIR=Box1
Host=192.168.1.100
mnt
```

but you can easily write it as

```
mnt Box1 192.168.1.100
```

I would also only parse your command line arguments in one place and create
a dedicated function for determine the appropriate ip address for your hosts.

I would also remove the ls call from your `mnt` function as mnt doesn't do what the name suggests. But this is a rather minor issue and I didn't change it in my code.

```
#!/bin/sh
# mount boxes by SSHFS

usage () {
    cat <<EOF
sshmnt -[c,s,u,h]
      -c Box1
      -s Box2
      -u unmount
      -h print this message

EOF
}

mnt(){

    if [ $# -ne 3 ] ; then
       echo "Wrong parameters for mnt - host dir port" >&2
       return 1
    fi

    host="$1"
    dir="$2"
    port="$3"
    sshfs jason@"$host":/home/jason /media/"$dir" \
    -C -p "$port" \
    -o reconnect,IdentityFile=/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && ls /media/"$dir"
}

umnt(){
    dir="$1"
    fusermount -u /media/"$dir"
}

get_host(){
    # check if on LAN
    lan="$(ip addr | grep .102/)"

    if [ -z "$lan" ] ; then
        echo XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        return 0
    fi

    case "$1" in
        Box1) echo 192.168.1.100 ;;
        Box2) echo 192.168.1.200 ;;
        *) echo "Unknown Parameter" >&2 && return 1 ;;
    esac
}

case "$1" in
    -c) mnt $(get_host Box1) Box1 port ;;
    -s) mnt $(get_host Box2) Box2 port ;;
    -u)
        mount | grep Box1 && umnt Box1
        mount | grep Box2 && umnt Box2
        ;;
     *) usage && exit 1;;
esac
```

Another suggestion is to get rid of all your hard coded paths and texts like, `/media/`, `/home/jason/` and `jason` and replace them with variables, e.g:

```
MOUNT_PREFIX=/media/
SSH_KEY=/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa
MOUNT_SOURCE=/home/jason
```

and just specify the user for your hosts in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Thanks Ulrich: that is very helpful. Would you mind expanding on your comment that "functions shouldn't depend on environment variables but use specified parameters"? I don't quite follow.

Comment: @jasonwryan ok updated the answer - also have a look at the last paragraph about your hard coded values

Comment: thank you for the added detail; it was a lightbulb moment. The extra variables are also a good suggestion.